Changing the alias of the statistics in etable "aer" output in r
I am exporting r feols regressions to latex.
I am using the command fitstat = c("my", "n") inside etable to present the mean of the dependent variable.
I want to present "Outcome Mean" instead of "Dependent variable mean"
But need help finding how to (not manually) change this.
Here is a reproducible code:
library(fixest)
est1 = feols(Ozone ~ i(Month) / Wind + Temp, data = airquality)
est2 = feols(Ozone ~ i(Month, Wind) + Temp | Month, data = airquality)

etable(est1, est2, tex = TRUE, fitstat = c("my", "n"))


This is the output of this code:
\begingroup
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
   \tabularnewline \midrule \midrule
   Dependent Variable: & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ozone}\\
   Model:                     & (1)            & (2)\\  
   \midrule
   \emph{Variables}\\
   Constant                   & -100.2$^{***}$ &   \\   
                              & (26.35)        &   \\   
   Month $=$ 6                & -54.99$^{**}$  &   \\   
                              & (26.34)        &   \\   
   Month $=$ 7                & 35.89$^{*}$    &   \\   
                              & (18.37)        &   \\   
   Month $=$ 8                & 44.52$^{**}$   &   \\   
                              & (18.05)        &   \\   
   Month $=$ 9                & -11.78         &   \\   
                              & (18.22)        &   \\   
   Temp                       & 2.042$^{***}$  & 2.042$^{***}$\\   
                              & (0.3078)       & (0.2242)\\   
   Wind $\times$ Month $=$ 5  & -1.086         & -1.086$^{***}$\\   
                              & (1.127)        & (0.1408)\\   
   Wind $\times$ Month $=$ 6  & 2.046          & 2.046$^{***}$\\   
                              & (1.784)        & (0.0398)\\   
   Wind $\times$ Month $=$ 7  & -5.616$^{***}$ & -5.616$^{***}$\\   
                              & (1.316)        & (0.1554)\\   
   Wind $\times$ Month $=$ 8  & -6.515$^{***}$ & -6.515$^{***}$\\   
                              & (1.220)        & (0.2203)\\   
   Wind $\times$ Month $=$ 9  & -1.349         & -1.349$^{**}$\\   
                              & (1.147)        & (0.3175)\\   
   \midrule
   \emph{Fixed-effects}\\
   Month                      &                & Yes\\  
   \midrule
   \emph{Fit statistics}\\
   Dependent variable mean    & 42.129         & 42.129\\  
   Observations               & 116            & 116\\  
   \midrule \midrule
   \multicolumn{3}{l}{\emph{Signif. Codes: ***: 0.01, **: 0.05, *: 0.1}}\\
\end{tabular}
\par\endgroup

and instead of
Dependent variable mean    & 42.129         & 42.129\\  

I want to have
Outcome mean    & 42.129         & 42.129\\  


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Instead of adding the incorrect outcome, please add an example which people can actually run to reproduce your problem. This would be much more useful than pushing the same incomplete question into the reopen queue twice.
